# Is the following cases function Riemann integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

I have the following question:

> Let $f$ be a function defined in the following interval: [0,1], such that:$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2 & 0\le x<\frac{1}{3} \\\\
> 0 & \frac{1}{3}\le x<\frac{2}{3} \\\\ 1 & \frac{2}{3}\le x<1 \end{cases}$$
> Is the given function Riemann integrable? if so calculate the integral via Riemann integral's definition.

***My attempt:***

My intuition says she is Riemann integrable, and the value of the integral is-1 since we can calculate the rectangles in the graph. However, I find it hard to prove that via Riemann integral's definition, because I cannot choose an equal partition $P$ for the upper and lower Darboux's sums to show $\sup_P L(P,f) = \inf_P U(P,f)$.

Comment: Can you not just do the ones spaced by $\frac1n$? There is a lemma that says that the Riemann integral exists if and only if those upper and lower sums converge to the same number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\varepsilon>0$, consider the partition $P_\varepsilon=\left\{0,\frac13-\frac\varepsilon4,\frac13,\frac23-\frac\varepsilon2,\frac23,1\right\}$. Then$$U(P_\varepsilon,f)=1\quad\text{and}\quad L(P_\varepsilon,f)=1-\varepsilon.$$Therefore, $f$ is Riemann-integrable, and $\int_0^1f=1$.

Comment: First, thank you so much! Second, you got that $1=U(P_{\varepsilon},f)\neq L(P_{\varepsilon},f)=1-\varepsilon$

and we need to have equality between them.

Comment: No, we *don't* have to have equality among them. Unless $f$ is constant, we *never* have $U(P,f)=L(P,f)$. But it follows from what I did that $\inf_PL(P,f)-\sup_PL(P,f)<\varepsilon$, for every $\varepsilon>0$, and that therefore $\inf_PL(P,f)=\sup_PL(P,f)$.

Comment: So you say that since she integrable then $\sup_P L(P,f) = \inf_P U(P,f)=1$?

Comment: Not at all. What I say is that since $\sup_PL(P,f)=\inf_PU(P,f)$, then $f$ is Riemann-integrable.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think you made a little mistake, or I just hardly understood if we take $\varepsilon = 0$ we do not get Upper or lower equal to $1$ if you can explain your moves it will be appreciated and nicely

Comment: Since I wrote that $\varepsilon>0$, it should be clear that *at no moment* I wrote (or suggested) that $\varepsilon=0$. Since, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a partition $P_\varepsilon$ such that $L(P,f)=1-\varepsilon$ and that $U(P,f)=1$, then, for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\sup_L(P,f)\geqslant1-\varepsilon$ and $\inf_P U(P,f)\leqslant1$, from which you can deduce that$$\inf_P U(P,f)-\sup_L(P,f)\leqslant\varepsilon.$$Since this occurs for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\inf_P U(P,f)-\sup_L(P,f)=0$. In other words, $\inf_P U(P,f)=\sup_L(P,f)$.

Comment: For which partition with which epsilon do you get that $\inf_P U(P,f)=1$, you said that $U(P,f)=1-\varepsilon$ so this sum can never reach 1, no? Do you have another approach with $ \lambda (P)< \delta $?

Comment: @aasc232 Your first question makes no sense, since $\inf_PU(P,f)$ is the infimum of the set of the set of numbers $U(P,f)$ for **all** partitions $P$. I never wrote that $U(P,f)=1-\varepsilon$. Finally, what are $\lambda$ and $\delta$?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say everything I said for the lower sum and not the upper.